# wxWidgets - _strnicmp' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, cmake, wxwidgets

I finally successfully (?) built wxWidgets on my computer. I downloaded version 3.1.0, installed it and executed:

```
dir C:\wxWidgets-3.1.0\build\msw
mingw32-make -j4 -f makefile.gcc SHARED=0 MONOLITHIC=1 UNICODE=1 BUILD=release
```

Within C:\wxWidgets-3.1.0\lib\gcc_lib, I have the following files:

```
224.202 libwxexpat.a
183.954 libwxjpeg.a
72.855.944 libwxmsw31u.a
353.238 libwxmsw31u_gl.a
255.066 libwxpng.a
92.410 libwxregexu.a
3.732.626 libwxscintilla.a
495.632 libwxtiff.a
98.352 libwxzlib.a
<DIR>          mswu
<DIR>          mswud
```

I tried to run one of the samples. But it throws the following error:

```
C:/wxWidgets-3.1.0/include/wx/wxcrt.h: In function 'int wxStrnicmp(const wxScopedCharBuffer&, const wxScopedCharBuffer&, size_t)':
C:/wxWidgets-3.1.0/include/wx/wxcrt.h:529:1: error: '_strnicmp' was not declared in this scope
```

WX_STRCMP_FUNC(wxStrnicmp, wxCRT_StrnicmpA, wxCRT_StrnicmpW, wxStrnicmp_String)

Obviously, the linker for linking my code does find the wxWidgets library. But it looks like the linker/compiler did not build wxWidgtes approrpiately.

Now my questions:

- Is it possible, that previously built *.a files (libwxzlib, libwxregexu, libwxpng) are causing this error?
- Is there any out-of-the-box (running) collection of commands to compile wxWidgets on Windows and setting the environment variables correctly?
- What environment variables need to be set?
- What is the actual cause of the error mentioned above?

Thank you!

//EDIT: 
I am compiling the sample (please find it at the bottom of this page: http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1/overview_helloworld.html) by using the following CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)

SET(wxWidgets_ROOT_DIR "C:/wxWidgets-3.1.0/")
SET(wxWidgets_LIB_DIR  "C:/wxWidgets-3.1.0/lib/gcc_lib")
SET(wxWidgets_INCLUDE_DIRS "C:/wxWidgets-3.1.0/lib/gcc_lib")
SET(wxWidgets_CONFIGURATION msw)

find_package(wxWidgets COMPONENTS net gl core base)
if(wxWidgets_FOUND)
    include(${wxWidgets_USE_FILE})
    add_executable(untitled ${SOURCE_FILES})
    target_link_libraries(untitled ${wxWidgets_LIBRARIES})
endif()
```

Comment: Is Visual Studio an option for you or you have to use `mingw`?

Comment: How do you compile the sample exactly?

Comment: @Sga: Theoretically, yes. But right now I want to understand what's going wrong- because of research :)

Comment: @VZ.: Based on the CMakeLists file described in the original post.

Comment: @KarloKraljic, if you successfully build wxWidgets library, you shuold be able to just do `cd wxWidgets/samples/minimal && mingw32-make -j4 -f makefile.gcc SHARED=0 MONOLITHIC=1 UNICODE=1 BUILD=release`. You SHOULD use the exact same command you build the library with when you building either the samples or your own software. And also you should use the same compiler version.

Comment: @KarloKraljic, just note that the command I posted above is exactly the same as the one you used to build the library. And you should just drop the CMake until you have a big project to compile/work on - just to verify the sample/successful compilation the command I posted is more than enough. Also final note - try to compile an official samples from the wxWidgets distribution, starting with minimal.

Comment: If you are planning to use Visual Studio replace mingw32-make with `nmake` and re-compile the wxWidgets.

Comment: @macroland, or even better - open the appropriate solution inside IDE, then select `Build->Batch Build....->Build All`.. After it finishes open wxWIdgets/samples/minimal/wxmsw<X>.sln and compile.

Comment: @Igor: Yes, that would be easier.